# NOT LIKE From two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get all usernames from Table A that do not exist in Table B with a specific MeetingID
Like iam trying to get Meetingid: 2, Table A should return the user Tested and leave the rest out of it. MeetingID 6 returns Test.
Is this possible with one query?

> **Table A:** ID, Username 1 Test 2 Tested 3 Testood
>
> **Table B:** Meetingid, Username 2 Test 2 Testood 6 Tested 6 Testood

This is the code i have been trying to get working:

```
SELECT members.username FROM members RIGHT JOIN attendmeeting ON
attendmeeting.username=members.username WHERE attendmeeting.username
NOT LIKE members.username ORDER BY username DESC
```

Table A is members and Table B is attendmeeting. I dont know how I can filter this out based on the Meeting id.

====================================================

EDIT:
Thanks to  Harsh Gupta this first part is working now.
Last thing is to filter out the NOT LIKE only using a specific meetingid with those members.

Current code:

```
SELECT members.username 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN attendmeeting 
ON attendmeeting.username = members.username 
WHERE attendmeeting.username IS NULL 
ORDER BY members.username DESC
```

Comment: You should use `NOT IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT username FROM members WHERE username NOT IN(SELECT username FROM attendmeeting WHERE meetingid=?) ORDER BY username ASC
```

Was the query I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which is your tableA and tableB:

```
SELECT members.username 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN attendmeeting 
ON attendmeeting.username = members.username 
WHERE attendmeeting.username IS NULL 
ORDER BY members.username DESC
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT members.username 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN attendmeeting 
ON attendmeeting.username = members.username 
WHERE attendmeeting.username IS NULL
    AND attendmeeting.username = 2
ORDER BY members.username DESC
```

HTH

Comment: This one returns me the contents of attendmeeting wich is B

Comment: Sorry, accidentally added the `NOT`. Corrected.

Comment: Very nice, this works. Can I also use a Where cause that filters based on this meetingid (Table B) like only use meetingid 6 or 2?

Comment: Yes, you can add those filters without any issues.

Comment: SELECT members.username FROM members RIGHT JOIN attendmeeting ON
attendmeeting.username=members.username WHERE attendmeeting.username
NOT LIKE members.username AND attendmeeting.meetingid LIKE '2' ORDER BY username DESC doesnt work, pretty new to the JOIN of SQL thank you for helping me this far :)

Comment: You are still using `attendmeeting.username NOT LIKE members.username`. This will not work for what you want.

Comment: Oh my mistake, how can I apply the filter to the right code? SELECT members.username 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN attendmeeting 
ON attendmeeting.username = members.username 
WHERE attendmeeting.username IS NULL
ORDER BY members.username DESC

Comment: Seems It wont let me apply meeting id to it: SELECT members.username 
FROM members 
LEFT JOIN attendmeeting 
ON attendmeeting.username = members.username 
WHERE attendmeeting.username IS NULL
    AND attendmeeting.meetingid = 14
ORDER BY members.username DESC (it returns nothing)